# Facebook OG meta data works only for some pages, not others; debugger hangs

Tags: facebook, drupal-7, seo, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

The title pretty much says it all: Facebbook reads *some* of my web pages' OG metatags and not others. I admit to being something of a novice when it comes to metatags. That being said, I don't understand at all what the problem is. Facebook's debugger tool hangs and eventually times out when it is run on some of these pages.

I'm using Drupal 7 with the (relatively straightforward) Metatag module. The page in question is this one:
http://objectneurotic.com/auto-generate-drum-patterns-in-ableton

Thank you!!!

EDIT: I did not include any code in my original post, so here is what my metatag section looked like--for the most part, anyway; since I corrected the code the other day, the error has been recreated for illustrative purposes.

**Ultimately, the problem was caused by an *og:image* tag that was erroneous; the source for the image was listed as an FTP destination, causing Facebook to fail completely to load any of the meta data..**

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="How-to: Let Ableton Generate MIDI Drum Variations for     You" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://objectneurotic.com/auto-generate-drum-patterns-in-ableton" />
<meta property="og:description" content="[long description...]" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2014-08-26T09:32:21-04:00" />
<meta property="og:image" content="ftps://ftp.objectneurotic.com[...]" /> <!-- THIS LINE -->
<meta property="og:image:type" content="img/png" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
```

Comment: In general, could you please include the relevant code (a minimal example) in your question? Otherwise a quesiton and its answers are of little use when the link rots or the page changes.

Comment: @unor Oops. I see your point. I am still getting used to using this website. Yes, I will do that in the future; I'll edit my post now to add in the code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have FTP link in og:image attribute which is mandatory. Use http or https instead.

Comment: I didn't even realize that I made that mistake! Thank you!